# Android MediaCodec with MediaProjection when screen rotated

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

when I record screen with MediaCodec, MediaMuxer and MediaProjection in Android device, the picture in video is too small when the screen gets rotated from portrait to landscape.

Does anyone have a solution to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R30rM.png)

I want recording video, perform same as the system screen recorder in Android.